# Taking the Derivative of $\frac {\sin(x^2)}{3x}$, which step is wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I'm trying to take the derivative of $\frac {\sin(x^2)}{3x}$.

Here are my steps:

$$\frac {d}{dx}\left[\frac {\sin(x^2)}{3x}\right]$$
Use the Quotient Rule:
$$\frac {3x\frac {d}{dx}[\sin(x^2)]-\sin(x^2)\frac {d}{dx}[3x]}{3x^2}$$

Simplify second part:

$$\frac {3x\frac {d}{dx} [\sin(x^2)]-3\sin(x^2)}{3x^2}$$

Use Chain Rule on first part:

$$\frac {d}{dx} [\sin(x^2)]= 2x(\cos(x^2))$$

Plug it into the numerator:

$$\frac {3x(2x)\cos(x^2)-3\sin(x^2)}{3x^2}$$

Simplify a little / Result:

$$\frac {6x^2\cos(x^2)-3\sin(x^2)}{3x^2}$$

Right answer: $$\frac {2x^2\cos(x^2)-\sin(x^2)}{3x^2}$$

So I messed something up, but I tried to redo the process multiple times and couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You have to square the *entire* denominator.

Comment: Also, use backslash in your $\LaTeX$ for sin and cosine.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! :)

Comment: You can move $3$ in the denominator out of differentiation in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adrian said in the comments, when you used quotient rule, the entire denominator should be squared, giving a denominator of $9x^2$ rather than $3x^2$.

This gives $$\frac {6x^2\cos(x^2)-3\sin(x^2)}{9x^2}=\frac {2x^2\cos(x^2)-\sin(x^2)}{3x^2}$$as required.

Edit: Just seen your comment - if you already have parentheses around the $3x$, then your answer is not wrong at all, it just needs to be simplified (as I have done above).

Comment: Argh.. thank you. No idea how I missed that.

Comment: No problem! It is easy to miss things when you are tired haha

Answer (score 1):

It is $$\frac{\cos(x^2)\cdot 2x\cdot3x-\sin(x^2)\cdot 3}{9x^2}$$
which simplifies to $$\frac{2 x^2 \cos \left(x^2\right)-\sin
   \left(x^2\right)}{3 x^2}$$